# build error: 'ParseCommandLineFlags' is not a member of 'google'

Tags: flags

i am trying to use the google flags on vs2013, my main function is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  google::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, true);
  google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);
 ...
}
```

and vs2013 reports two build error:
error C2039: 'ParseCommandLineFlags' : is not a member of 'google'
error C3861: 'ParseCommandLineFlags': identifier not found

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem between different versions of GFLAGS on different servers, instead of explicitly using `google` or `gflags` namespace I used the `GFLAGS_NAMESPACE` namespace which is defined in `gflags/gflags_declare.h`, so it will always use the right namespace depending on the installed version.

So you can change this:

```
google::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, true);
```

to this:

```
#ifdef GFLAGS_NAMESPACE
    GFLAGS_NAMESPACE::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, true);
#else
    google::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, true);
#end
```